# Convert a list of 3D coordinates in string format to a list of floats

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 3D coordinates in the format as list_X.

```
list_X =' [43.807  7.064 77.155], [35.099  3.179 82.838], [53.176052  -5.4618497 83.53082  ], [39.75858    1.5679997 74.76174  ], [42.055664  2.459083 80.89183 ]'
```

I want to convert into floats as below

```
list_X =[43.807  7.064 77.155], [35.099  3.179 82.838], [53.176052  -5.4618497 83.53082  ], [39.75858    1.5679997 74.76174  ], [42.055664  2.459083 80.89183 ]
```

I was trying as below which doesn't work

```
list1=[float(x) for x in list_X]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up the string to fit in the format of a `list` (i.e., add surrounding square brackets (`[]`) to contain all of the 3D coordinates, and separate the values by commas), and then use the `json.loads` method.

```
import json

list_X ='[[43.807, 7.064, 77.155], [35.099, 3.179, 82.838], [53.176052, -5.4618497, 83.53082], [39.75858, 1.5679997, 74.76174], [42.055664, 2.459083, 80.89183]]'

print(json.loads(list_X))
```

---

```
# Output

[[43.807, 7.064, 77.155], [35.099, 3.179, 82.838], [53.176052, -5.4618497, 83.53082], [39.75858, 1.5679997, 74.76174], [42.055664, 2.459083, 80.89183]]
```

Comment: Do you know any faster way we can convert into this format?